# How to send data over AXI Stream using Xiling VIP IP

Tags: system-verilog, xilinx, vivado, test-bench

I'm trying to use AXI Stream Verification IP but I cannot figure out how to use it in slave mode. How can I get the data out of agent:

```
import axi4stream_vip_v1_0_1_pkg::*;
import axis_vip_master_pkg::*;
import axis_vip_slave_pkg::*;

module shift_register_vip();
    logic aclk;
    logic aresetn;
    logic [63:0] in_tdata;
    logic        in_tvalid;
    logic        in_tready;
    logic [23:0] out_tdata;
    logic        out_tvalid;
    logic        out_tready;

    axis_vip_master vip_master(.aclk(aclk), .aresetn(aresetn), .m_axis_tdata(in_tdata), .m_axis_tvalid(in_tvalid), .m_axis_tready(in_tready));
    shift_register dut(.aclk(aclk), .aresetn(aresetn), .s_axis_data(in_tdata), .s_axis_valid(in_tvalid), .s_axis_ready(in_tready), .m_axis_data(out_tdata), .m_axis_valid(out_tvalid), .m_axis_ready(out_tready));
    axis_vip_slave vip_slave(.aclk(aclk), .aresetn(aresetn), .s_axis_tdata(out_tdata), .s_axis_tvalid(out_tvalid), .s_axis_tready(out_tready));

    initial aclk = 1;
    always #5ns aclk <= ~aclk;

    axis_vip_master_mst_t master_agent;
    axis_vip_slave_slv_t slave_agent;

    mailbox mbx;
    mailbox sbx;

    task generator();
        for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) begin
            logic [7:0] word = $random();
            mbx.put(word);
            sbx.put(word);
        end
    endtask

    task run_master();
        while (1) begin
            axi4stream_transaction trans = master_agent.driver.create_transaction();
            logic [63:0] din;
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) begin
                mbx.get(din[i * 8 +: 8]);
            end
            trans.set_data_beat(din);
            master_agent.driver.send(trans);
        end
    endtask

    initial begin
        master_agent = new("master", vip_master.inst.IF);
        slave_agent = new("slave", vip_slave.inst.IF);
        mbx = new();
        sbx = new();
        master_agent.start_master();
        slave_agent.start_slave();
        aresetn <= 0;
        repeat (4) @(posedge aclk);
        aresetn <= 1;
        fork
            generator();
            run_master();
        join
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to print every slave transaction:

```
    axi4stream_monitor_transaction mon_trans;
    xil_axi4stream_data_byte InputData[2];
    slave_agent.set_verbosity(0);
    slave_agent.start_monitor();
    forever begin
        slave_agent.monitor.item_collected_port.get(mon_trans);
        mon_trans.get_data(InputData);
        $display("Transaction: %d, %d", InputData[0], InputData[1]);
    end
```